# Not receiving notification when app is in foreground also not receiving payload data when clicking on notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

So, I am trying to get notification when app is in background or foreground and trying to send data payload from firebase console to android app activity, but I am getting this

1. I am receiving notification when app is in background
2. Not receiving notification when app is in foreground
3. Also, datapayload which I am getting from firebase console, with key "str", is not showing in activity

Please tell me where is the problem and how it will be solved.

```
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingServic";

public FirebaseMessagingService() {
}

String value = "0";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        value = remoteMessage.getData().get("str"); //key text in quotes

    }
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); //get title
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); //get message

    sendNotification(title, message, value);
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
  /*  if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {



        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title: " + title);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + message);


    }*/
}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {

}

private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody, String value) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CS101noti.class);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putString("body", value).apply();

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have solved it :)

You just need to send data payload from REST API or Postman, and get data values in Java code, 
it will work like Charm :)